# 1.9.4.x to 2.3.6 data Migration not able to ignore table

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

When migrating data using Adobe's data migration tool I am receiving the following error... (see below). I have added `sales_flat_quote` to the source ignore document section. Yet I am still receiving the error.

**Output Error**

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'a6b7f26c_restore.sales_flat_quote' 
doesn't exist, query was: SELECT DISTINCT  `child`.`quote_id`
   FROM `email_abandoned_cart` AS `child`
   LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_quote` AS `parent` ON child.quote_id = parent.entity_id WHERE
 (child.quote_id IS NOT NULL) AND (parent.entity_id IS NULL)
```

and

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'a6b7f26c_restore.sales_flat_quote' 
doesn't exist
```

**map.xml file**

```
        <ignore>
            <document>sales_flat_quote</document>
        </ignore>
```

Comment: Add `email_abandoned_cart` table in ignore in map.xml and try again. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @RahulBarot Still same error I added the ignore rule under both source and destination for map.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 100% fix to the issue since each data migration situation will be a little bit different.

1. Option 1 Try clearing cache and re-running... `php bin/magento cache:flush`
2. Option 2 Skip the pre-check / Integrity by commenting it out from the config.xml file `<step title="Data Integrity Step"><integrity>XXX/xxx/xxx/</integrity></step>`

The final errors after data migration will give you moe insight as to what the real problem is. In my case it was an extension that needed to be disabled.